# lwc called in aura component problem

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, navigation, popup

I have an aura component that I share with you its code and which uses another lwc component, the treatment that I want is that when I click on the save of the aura component, the aura component closes and the lwc component is displayed as a popup.
I add that the aura component I call it in an action, so I want once I click on save the aura closes and the lwc launches.

The problem I have now is that the lwc launches when I click on the save of the aura and closes with the aura closing automatically, we can't even see it correctly because it launches at the time of closing the component aura for not even a second and closes with the closing of the aura .

How can I fix this.
=> Aura

- Component :

```
<aura:component controller="SignController"   implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" 
                access="global" >
    
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler event="BGSIGCAP:SignatureCapturedEvt" action="{!c.handleCaptured}"/>
        <aura:attribute name="showPopup" type="boolean" default="false" />
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
        <aura:attribute name="device" type="string"/> 
       <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/>
       <aura:attribute name="cssStyle" type="String"/>
       <aura:attribute name="showLWC" type="Boolean" default="false" />
       <aura:html tag="style">
       .slds-modal__container {
         }
          .slds-modal__content{
            overflow-y:hidden !important;
            height:unset !important;
            max-height:unset !important;
        }
           }
       </aura:html>

    <p style="text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
    color: rgb(3, 192, 74);
    font-weight: 500;">{!$Label.c.Sign_Msg}</p>
    <BGSIGCAP:SignatureCapture recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                               completeMsg="-------------"
                               enterMsg="{!$Label.c.sign}"
                               saveButtonLabel="{!$Label.c.Save}"
                               clearButtonLabel="{!$Label.c.Cancel}"
                               skipToCapture = "true"/>
        
      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showLWC}">
        <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.ModalWidthCSStOW}" />
        <c:sendPDF devise="{!v.device}" onvaluechange="{!c.getValueFromLwc}" />
    </aura:if>
    
</aura:component>
```

-Controller :

```
({
    doInit: function (cmp , event , helper) {
                helper.Update(cmp, event, helper);
},

   getValueFromLwc: function(component, event, helper) {
        if (event.getParam('valuett') === "teste") {
            const dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
            dismissActionPanel.fire();

            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        }
    },
  
    handleCaptured: function (component, event, helper) {
        let message = 'Signature captured for record id ' + event.getParam('recordId');
        const from = event.getParam('name');
        if (from !== undefined) {
            message += ' from instance ' + from;
        }
        message += ' - closing action';
        const toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "type": 'info',
            "title": 'Signatured Captured',
            "message": message
        });
        toastEvent.fire();

        const dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        
        component.set("v.showLWC", true);

           }
})
```

=> LWC

-HTML:

```
<template>
   
        <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li class="slds-align_absolute-center">

<h1>Teste</h1>                </li>
                
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          
    </template>
```